# Как создать дочерний процесс который не зависит от родителя, то есть не умирает при родителе с++

Tags: c++, linux, bash

У меня есть одна консоль и надо сделать так чтоб мой код создал отдельные процессы и когда его родителя закроют, то дети продолжали работать

Comment: вообще говоря, когда закрывают _только_ родителя дети и так продолжают работать... для того чтобы процессы не получали назойливые сигналы даже при закрытии сессии или когда убивают рабочую группу родителя, см. что такое *демон* и *демонизация*.

Comment: [man 2 setsid](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setsid) (и SEE ALSO там)